# Errors with sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt

Whenever I type in `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal, these are the errors I receive:

```
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en_US  
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages [63,4 kB]
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en_US      
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en_US        
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages [24,4 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1 388 B]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                  
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 259 kB in 5s (48,9 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/revl/codimension/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/revl/codimension/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/tor/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/tor/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/tor64/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/tor64/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What does this mean? I appreciate any and all help! :)

I run Ubuntu 13.10, I recently installed it and am overall quite happy with it.

Answer (score -2):

that it's becouse the source tor 64 is not updated, and not ready for saucy get, codimension too, for cdrom, just uncheck cdrom on software source, and there you can uncheck the other sources until it ready for soucy.

Comment: I'm a total noob when it comes to Ubuntu so I don't really know what you're referring to. Can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: try opening software source (press ubuntu button and write it), and manage your repos, also you can try installing yppa for manage external repos (tor64, codimension etc.),  To install YPPA Manager on Ubuntu open Terminal (Press Alt+F2 and type: gnome-terminal -or- Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:
Terminal Commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager

Comment: When I try to type in: sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager in the terminal I get the following error: nikz@Nikz:~$ sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
E: The update command takes no arguments

Comment: sorry, but textbox not respet new lines,:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager

Comment: I still get the same error message as presented in my first post with that command, dansanti. This is getting quite frustrating, anybody?

Comment: you have to open this 2 programas that i say, software source or y-ppa-manager , when you open one of those, find your repo , example tor64 and uncheck it then close the program and update again, look, just like this image , but you uncheck the repos with problem and update again http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xzr5OBlyzjo/Ty_rsQTTEjI/AAAAAAAAHoY/N4O7DJ1j6Ik/s1600/software-sources.png

Comment: if you can't uncheck, manually delete repo with problem , open a terminal and write sudo nautilus /etc/apt/sources.list.d/